In Pivot columns are coming in reverse order
Recently i have observed in the Pivot table of excel while choosing the Field Name. The order of fields should be like Inv1 and Inv2 where as it is coming as Inv2 and Inv1.
How do i preserve the same order in which Field name are chosen?

I don't want to manually change the order of Field name in pivot

The columns will appear on the pivot, in the same order as you arrange them in the right bottom corner. If you want to have the columns arranged in the alphabetical order (in your case 'Inv1','Inv2'), do this:
Right click on any of the columns in the pivot -> Click on 'Sort' -> Select the order. See image below.
Sorting the columns in a pivot
